# django templates loops

Tags: python, django

Can I loop through two arrays/lists in django templates simultaneously?

Something like this:

```
# views.py

a = [{'a':'apple','b':'banana','c':'clementine'},
     {'a':'aunt','b':'brother','c':'cousin'},
     {'a':'ant','b':'bat','c':'cat'}]
b = [{'d':'dave','f':'fred'},
     {'d':'dason','f':'ford'},
     {'d':'dance','f':'flamenco']

# something.html

{% for x, y in a and b %}
    {{ x.a }},{{ x.c }}<br>
    {{ y.f }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists in your view, then iterate through the resulting list in your template.

```
# views.py
ab = zip(a,b)

# template
{% for x,y in ab %}
    {{ x.a }},{{ x.c }}<br>
    {{ y.f }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: cool. I'll give it a go. I only ask because there are aspects of the model I want to use when I am iterating over the form